# I want to select only First div heading from the html code is there a way to do it

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div class="first tempbg">
        First div Text
        <section id="sec1" class="">
            Section 1 Text
            <div class="insidefirst tempbg">
                Div 1 Text
                <p class="">Paragraph 1</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <article id="art1" class="">
            Article 1 Text
            <div class="insidefirst tempbg">
                Div 2 Text
                <p class="">Paragraph 2</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use `id` for that `div`

Comment: Its not working iJust want ot select this from the code First div Text

Comment: Do you mean this `<div class="first tempbg">` one?

Comment: Yeah the text between <div class="first tempbg"> and <section id="sec1" class=""> If u can send the selector it would be a great help

Comment: Use `<span></span>` tag for the text. Follow this `<span id="text">First div Text</span>` you can use class attribute for this as well.

Comment: i cant change the code this is from a site i cant change anything i have to select from this only

Answer (score 0):

first way :

First div Text
            
                Section 1 Text
                
                    Div 1 Text
                    Paragraph 1
                
            
            
                Article 1 Text
                
                    Div 2 Text
                    Paragraph 2

div.section.insidefirst {
#your css
background-color:red
}

second way:
div.section:first-child {
background-color:red
}

The ":first-child" selector allows you to target the first element immediately inside another element. It is defined in the CSS Selectors Level 3 spec as a “structural pseudo-class”, meaning it is used to style content based on its relationship with parent and sibling content.